# JQuery Mobile: Option to labeling Images in Gallery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have some pictures that are taken from camera with filename that is auto-generated and I have a list of labels that I need the user to assign to each of the pictures. What is the best way to do this with JQuery/Mobile?

I am thinking to use the Select Menus option, but it can't display image on it.

Thanks
Halomoan

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you are working on some mobile platform very first though you haven't mentioned it. Jquery mobile is a javascript library which can be used to develop mobile support web pages. It has simplified methods moreover using jquery. jquery mobile cannot be used stand alone to access mobile system. It only enhance web technologies to mobile. you need to use phoneGap (another js library with plugins to build hybrid apps) to use mobile features using java script.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/index.html

use jqm to design UIs and use phonegap to access mobile file system.